# Get Attribute Value From Simple XML Using JQuery / Javascript

Tags: jquery, xml

I tring to get the attribute value from the following simple xml using my javascript.

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ParentNode Symbol="$"><Row book = "test" price ="80"/></ParentNode>
```

jQuery: `$('ParentNode').attr('Symbol');`

The JQuery is working fine if the xml code is

```
<ParentNode Symbol="$"><Row book = "test" price ="80"/>   </ParentNode>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
var string  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ParentNode Symbol="$"><Row book = "test" price ="80"/></ParentNode>';

var $doc = $.parseXML(string);
console.log($($doc).find('ParentNode').attr('Symbol'))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PcLSb/)

Comment: @Arun P Johny, what if i have special characters in book tag. i.e <Row book = "Special `~@#$%^&*()_+-=}{|:;&apos;/.,<>?  message&*()" price ="80"/>, how can i deal with them?

Comment: The fiddle's console output is '$'.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(xml).find("ParentNode").attr("Symbol");
```

Try this

Comment: Hi , It returns 'undefined'